# Display Full Date {DD-MM-YYYY} in Hover Text, python, plotly

Tags: python, pandas, date, plotly, hover

I'm plotting a chart that spans multiple years using the python plotly library - `import plotly.express as px`

When the chart is displayed in full, the `date` that is shown in the hover text only includes the month and year `M-YYYY`.

[image]

Yet when it is zoomed in the full date is displayed `M-DD-YYYY`

[image]

Are there any settings in or related to `hovertemplate` or `hovermode` that will allow the full date to be displayed at all times?

This can be replicated in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

start=pd.to_datetime("2016-01-01")
end=pd.to_datetime("2022-12-31")
length = end - start

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start="2016-01-01",end="2022-12-31"),
                   'Value':np.random.randint(5,30,size=length.days+1)})
fig = px.area(df, x='Date', y="Value", 
              title = "Example Data",)

fig.update_traces(line_color='firebrick')
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the formatting string to apply to hover data, use `hover_data` :

```py
fig = px.area(df, x='Date', y="Value",
              title="Example Data",
              hover_data={'Date': '|%B %d, %Y'})
```

@see

- [Disabling or customizing hover of columns in plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#disabling-or-customizing-hover-of-columns-in-plotly-express)
- [d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

First, create a date format string for the hover text

```
date_format = "%b %d, %Y"
```

Then, update the x-axis `tickformat` to the desired date format

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat=date_format)
```

But this solution will format `x-axis` label as well

Comment: This is a good workaround, thanks! I would prefer it didn't change the `x-axis` though.